# Google Chrome Extension: attempt to authenticate user, using launchWebAuthFlow ends up with 'Authorization page could not be loaded'

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension

Good day to **you** **all**!

**My goal:** authenticate user with Google account, access related token_id and pass it on a server for further process.

**What I'm trying to do**: I'm trying to get token_id, using *launchWebAuthFlow* from background script:

**background.js:**

```
var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
var clientId = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.client_id);
var scopes = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));
//var redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('https://' + chrome.runtime.id + '.chromiumapp.org');
//var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL(chrome.runtime.id);
var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2");

console.log(redirectUri);
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' +
    '?client_id=' + clientId +
    '&response_type=id_token' +
    '&access_type=offline' +
    '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri +
    '&scope=' + scopes;

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
        'url': url,
        'interactive': true
    },
    function (redirectedTo) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
"permissions": [
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
"unlimitedStorage",
"contextMenus",
"cookies",
"tabs",
"notifications",
"identity"
]
"oauth2": {
"client_id": "Some client id",
"scopes": [
  "openid", "email", "profile"
]
```

}

**Result:** at first time I got a google authentication page, and after submiting I get:

*Authorization page could not be loaded. erro*r

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid Chrome logon instead of Google logon? If it is no difference for you, chrome.identity.getAuthToken is the answer, it works quite smoothly, but forces you to log into Chrome.

Comment: Well yes, that works fine - in the result I can get an access token to reach related api, though I need a way to get token id, avoiding Chrome logon  .. is it possible at all?

Comment: is the user logged into chrome?

Comment: Yes the user logged into chrome. But goal remains the same - get token id

Comment: If user is logged into chrome, chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true/false}, function (token) {}); will give you the token in the callback. 
Interactive param determines what to do if the user isn't logged on -- true will give him Chrome's logon page, false will set the error.

If you have troubles with that, it's usually problem with scopes, client_id or the authorization for that scopes and id.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Same issue here: @MikeTyukanov: getAuthToken only returns the access_token. I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the id_token (JWT) and the refresh_token. These additional tokens are returned by the server-side equivalent: getToken() (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingresponse). There are a number of threads on github suggesting the OpenID alternative, but many of us are getting the "Authorization page could not be loaded" error.

Comment: I found my error: to debug copy the URL into the browser and you'll get a more specific error than the one above. E.g., redirect_uri_mismatch (which may mean either the registered redirect_url doesn't match or the client ID is incorrect -- in my case, stale).